# Online French dictionary for mathematics

Tags: ressources, mathématiques, dictionnaires

I am reading a book and several papers in mathematics which are in French. Sometimes I have problems in translating (understanding) some words or phrases. I am looking for some online (or downloadable) dictionary.

Comment: You need to be careful with some math-speficic terms. For example, *variété* in French stands most often for a *manifold* which may be confusing when *varieties* mean something different in English. For these kind of terms, it's probably best to check the translation via switching Wikipedia from French to English.

Comment: Asking about *general* recommendation for dictionaries isn't considered constructive (see http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/3164/what-is-a-good-native-french-dictionary-and-grammar-book). Your question is though very interesting, because mathematics vocabulary, locutions, and conventions are very specific and resources are not easily accessible either online or offline.

Comment: you should look for the maths word in the english wikipedia, and then click to the french page to have the translation.

Comment: Some additional tricky points: French wikipedia is pretty hit-or-miss for math definitions, especially compared to English wikipedia. Also, to expand on Mark's remark, there are many other false friends. e.g. «sommable» (for a series) would translate as "absolutely summable" in English. There are also some tricky things in the names of topological spaces satisfying the various separation axioms.

Comment: My suggestion would be to find a francophone mathematician and invite them to coffee or cake in exchange for answering a handful of questions.

Answer (score 6):

I have found the following resources to look up for mathematical words and phrases in French:

[Online list:](https://reyssat.users.lmno.cnrs.fr/dico/dicoaf.html)

[Downloadable pdf file:](http://www.math.umn.edu/%7Ekwlan/documents/french-glossary.pdf)

Answer (score 2):

Il faut savoir chercher, à moins que votre recherche soit ancienne, aujourd’hui on trouve :

[https://ensiwiki.ensimag.fr/index.php?title=Lexique_scientifique_français-anglais](https://ensiwiki.ensimag.fr/index.php?title=Lexique_scientifique_fran%C3%A7ais-anglais)

https://gargantua.polytechnique.fr/siatel-web/app/linkto/mICYYYTALpZ

http://www.bibmath.net/trans/index.php

Le dernier ayant la réponse que je cherchais et que les autres n’avaient pas